# Is it possible to hide columns in jQuery Grid by default?

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I have been working with the [jQuery Grid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) the past few days and one thing I have not found any documentation on yet is the ability to hide a column by default.

The reason I want this is that I'm building my JSON w/ every property of my object yet my grid might only show 75% of these as valid columns.  I want the ability to pass back more JSON than I actually use, and one way I thought to accomplish this would be to hide the columns I'm not using.

Any other suggestions are welcome, but I would prefer the ability to push down a larger list of JSON than I actually use by default.

Comment: Cheers for asking this question...I've been using Flexigrid, but development has gone dark, jqGrid looks v.nice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the colModel initializer array, you can specify

```
hidden: true
```

on any of the columns.

Comment: simple and helpful! tnx.

Answer (score 0):

What version of flexgrid are you using...? my one doesn't accept hidden property in colModel

it does accept

```
hide: true
```